# WordPress/PHP Redirect with % sign in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, character-encoding

I've spent a lot of time researching this to no avail. I've tried PHP file redirects, htaccess hacks, and WordPress redirect plugins. Nothing gives the results.

My client wants to redirect `www.example.com/1%` to `www.example.com/causes`. I know the percent sign is a reserved character, but can someone tell me the easiest way to incorporate this?

Ideally, I'd like to have the coding in a place that won't be overwritten with theme updates.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite? Why /1%?  Why not /loc=1 or something?

Comment: Is the request uri /1 is really a page or something? Any why there is a `%` character?

Answer (score 0):

Hello the following plugin may help you.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/

here to can change the url of the current post/page to any url that you want.

let me whether this works.

Comment: No this does not. Although I create a page with title "1%", WordPress resolves permalink as "1-2". There is no overriding it. And WordPress does not allow illegal characters in permalink (which is root of this problem). Thanks though. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could add in a 
RedirectMatch to find any URL's in the format you are looking for (with the percent sign) and replace them with a symbol that wordpress allows in permalinks:

For example:

```
RedirectMatch www.example.com\/(\d{0,2})(?:%)(.*) www.example.com/($1)-YAY-($2)
```

[image]

http://regexr.com/3fm4i